# Python Dataframes: Filter a dataframe according to groupby condition

Tags: python, dataframe

hi I have a dataframe like below:

```
ID    date          
1     01.01.2017        
1     01.01.2017        
1     01.04.2017        
2     01.01.2017        
2     01.01.2017        
2     01.02.2017
```

What I want is to filter the id's which the related min and max of the dates' difference is 3 days. The final dataframe should be like this since only id 1 matches the condition:

```
ID    date          
1     01.01.2017        
1     01.01.2017        
1     01.04.2017
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Groupby.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) with a custom `lambda` function to check if the difference between the maximum date and the minimum is of `3` days:

```
d = datetime.timedelta(days=3)
df.groupby('ID').date.filter(lambda x: (x.max() - x.min()) == d)

ID
1   2017-01-01
1   2017-01-01
1   2017-01-04
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mask and then use it as a filter:

```
import pandas as pd

# create sample data-frame
data = [[1, '01.01.2017'], [1, '01.01.2017'], [1, '01.04.2017'],
        [2, '01.01.2017'], [2, '01.01.2017'], [2, '01.02.2017']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['id', 'date'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

# create mask
mask = df.groupby('id')['date'].transform(lambda x: (x.max() - x.min()).days == 3)

# filter
result = df[mask]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
   id       date
0   1 2017-01-01
1   1 2017-01-01
2   1 2017-01-04
```